# Parsing a JSON file - Subarray or inside square brackets node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse a JSON API response using node.js. I have everything down but at one point (and this has to be simple), I'm completely stuck on how to approach the subarray or something.

Here's an example of what I want to accomplish. (Ignore the TF2 theme)

```
"AWPer Hand":
{
    "defindex": [851],
    "prices": {
        "1": {
            "Tradable": {
                "Craftable": [{
                    "value": 15.33,
                    "currency": "metal",
                    "difference": -0.33,
                    "last_update": 1469842566,
                    "value_raw": 15.33
                }]
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "Tradable": {
                "Craftable": [{
                    "value": 3,
                    "currency": "metal",
                    "difference": 0.17,
                    "last_update": 1466442983,
                    "value_raw": 3
                }]
            }
        },
        "11": {
            "Tradable": {
                "Craftable": [{
                    "value": 5,
                    "currency": "keys",
                    "difference": -4.75,
                    "last_update": 1469371613,
                    "value_raw": 102.475
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the proper format as there's a lot inside the file, though to get the format of how it looks mostly I have this line of code that works

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var price = obj['response']['items'][itemName]['prices'][quality]['Tradable']['Craftable']
```

(The example response would be the [itemName] on wards)

Inside the craftable there's a subarray around square brackets, how would I parse this properly inside node.js to get the "value_raw" ID?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think the easiest way would be

```
price[0].value_raw
```

since its and array which contains an object

Comment: Op! That's exactly it. Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple, though I never played with javascript and rarely touched json!

Comment: you are welcome :) i usually make similar mistakes when i'm tired and still coding

Answer (score 1):

> *Inside the craftable there's a subarray around square brackets, how would I parse this properly inside node.js to get the "value_raw" ID?*

Here the `craftable` consists of an array of Objects - even though it only has one Object in it.  To access that Object one only has to define the index value of that item - here that is 0: `obj[..etc..]['Craftable'][0]`

The properties of the `Craftable[0]' Object are available by the usual JavaScript .dot notation. EG...

```
obj. (.etc.) .Craftable[0].difference;
obj. (.etc.) .Craftable[0].value_raw;
```

... or bracket notation.

```
obj[..etc..]['Craftable'][0]['difference'];
obj[..etc..]['Craftable'][0]['value_raw'];
```

.dot notation is generally recommended where Object keys are not being access dynamically.